# Bulk add/remove accounts to/from SBS2003 POP3 connector

Tags: windows-sbs-2003, pop3, bulk-action

Is this possible?

I (attempt to, at least) maintain our SBS2003 box, which uses POP3 Connector to retrieve email. I am regularly asked to add/remove several accounts at once, usually for the same domain, and it is a laborious process to type in the details one at a time - since the only thing that varys across the accounts is the username/password/mailbox, it would be nice to be able to import from CSV or something.

Obviously, there is no way to do this through the standard interface (if there is I shall be annoyed that I missed it) but could it be done by manipulating the details directly wherever they are stored? Come to that, where *are* they stored? It must be somewhere in AD, in an ini file, or in the registry I guess - if someone could point me in the direction of this I could do all the legwork myself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the POP3 collector config in SBS 2003 is stored in two encrypted binary files:

- C:\Program Files\Microsoft Windows Small Business Server\Networking\POP3\IMBData.dat
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft Windows Small Business Server\Networking\POP3\IMBData.bak

There is no tool available to edit these

If you use the POP3 collector tool quite heavily I would suggest in investing in something like [MapiLab's Native POP3 Connector](http://www.mapilab.com/exchange/pop3_connector/) as it's a lot more flexible. I've used this in the past as the standard one shipped with SBS is incredibly unreliable and flaky.

Comment: Many thanks for this, I will have a look at trying to reverse engineer the file you have pointed me to and if I cannot I will probably use AutoHotKey as suggested by @Starfish. I would like to avoid paying for anything to sort this problem out, so probably won't go for MapiLab's software, but thanks for the advice. Now that I have the location of the file it seems that my Google-fu was not up to the job when I initially looked at this, I can find many references to it. FYI, while the file is not just text based it is largely UTF-16, so I am hopeful that I can still script this.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not familiar with SBS2003, I have been in similar situations where I had to manually edit or enter a batch of nearly identical items. If someone else doesn't provide a solution to directly edit the files, I recommend using [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to automate the data entry as a workaround. It's a tool to record and play back mouse and keyboard events. It includes a script recorder which will let you run through the process once and output a script to reproduce your keyboard and mouse events. Then you can edit the script to read values from a CSV file and loop through the actions to do the data entry (see [Loop command docs](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/LoopParse.htm)).

AutoHotKey also can create GUIs, so I recommend creating a simple GUI that shows all of the items read from the CSV file along with a button to click to process the selected entry. This is dead simple in AutoHotKey's language and only takes a few lines of code. Using the GUI will let you run through the process one by one in case something goes wrong in the middle of processing your entries.

Comment: I have looked at AutoHotKey for doing stuff like this before, although I have never yet actually had to use it. Now that I have the file where the data is stored I am going to attempt to reverse engineer it and build something that will allow me to script the manipulation of the file, rather than scripting the GUI. If I cannot do this with a reasonable amount of effort/time I will use AHK, so enjoy this delicious +1 I have bestowed upon you :-)